# How to install software which is on my pendrive?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, usb-installation

I'm new to the world of Linux, how can I install software which is my pendrive? I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 X32.

Comment: "new to linux" Then how did you install a version that has been removed from the official website? 13.10 is old, obsolete and dangerous to use. We do not support end of life versions.

Comment: previously i have downloaded this. is this dangerous to use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What software are you trying to install ?**

The package should be a `.deb` file or else it won't be installed.
If it is an `.exe` file then it won't work because it is only for Windows.

Download the `.deb` file of the software that you want to install.

Comment: Why don't ask the OP so you can better inform OP on what to do.